# Parse Error Exception

Tags: xml

I am parsing a weather data feed and it works with certain locations but errors out with this message on some locations:

> 09-22 10:40:33.364: WARN/System.err(3347): org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 465, column 29: not well-formed (invalid token)

Any ideas what might be happening?

Here is a snippet of the xml:

```
                <hour time="11 AM">
                    <url>http://www.....</url>
                    <obsdate>9/22/2010</obsdate>
                    <txtshort>Parcialmente soleado</txtshort>
                    <weathericon>03</weathericon>
                    <temperature>26</temperature>
                    <feelslike>29</feelslike>
                </hour>

                <hour time="12 PM">
                    <url>http://www.....</url>
                    <obsdate>9/22/2010</obsdate>
                    <txtshort>Parcialmente soleado</txtshort>
                    <weathericon>03</weathericon>
                    <temperature>26</temperature>
                    <feelslike>29</feelslike>
                </hour>
```

Line 465 is the 'hour' tag with the 12pm attribute value.  I have logged parse code and it is reading the xml up until it reaches this line.

Comment: How about posting your actual parsing code and a snippet of raw XML that's failing?

Comment: I don't believe that it is my code for it works on some feeds and not others from the same source just different locations.

Comment: @taraloca: Is it a public weather service? Can we have a look at the original file which you got?

Comment: it is not a public weather service.

Comment: I've restored the original indenting and I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: Figured out the problem.  Needed to set encoding for the InputSource.  This application takes in multiple languages.  What I did was declare a variable...  private static final String ENCODING = "iso-8859-1"; and then inputSource.setEncoding(ENCODING);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually turned out to be an unrecognized character in parsing an XML document.  What I did to fix this was to include the encoding type like this: (choose the encoding that matches your XML document)

```
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(is);
//inputSource.setEncoding("iso-8859-1");
inputSource.setEncoding("utf-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

The error says it's occurring in column 29, and the line that you've said is the line containing the error is only 18 characters long.  In all likelihood, this means one of two things:  either that line contains non-printing characters that we can't see, one of which is one of the small handful of characters that aren't allowable in XML, or there's an off-by-one error somewhere and the error's occurring in the next line - probably in the URL that you've redacted.

Comment: That's not right, before my edit (for readability) the line was 36 characters long, the 29th character is the 1.

Answer (score 0):

Before attempting to read any xml file, it's always advisable **to check for well-formedness of the xml document you are attempting to read**. In this case, try to put a well-formedness condition around the xml feed you get from the weather data feed before parsing it. Using C#.Net this can be done as follows:-

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.loadxml(rawXMLcontent);
```

If this fails it goes to exception block. You can handle the feed in the exception block accordingly. This assures that you never get any parse exceptions. I hope it helps.

Comment: I think if you look at the error closely, you'll see that it's being thrown by the XML parser - in short, OP is already performing exactly the well-formedness check that you're suggesting.

Comment: @Robert Yeah I do see that the error is related to the attribute value that easily by-passes the well-formedness condition.

Comment: Easily bypasses?  The error message *says* that the document's not well-formed.

Comment: The message says the token is not well-formed but not the document itself. There is huge difference between token and document I think. Checkinf for wellformedness does check for document but not for the attribute values or CDATA values. I think the problem over here is with the values and nothing to do with XML syntax which is quite ok.