# SAXException when parsing the character "°"

Tags: java, xml-parsing, saxparser

I'm having some troubles with the RSS feed parser I made, based on `SAXParser`.
I extended the `DefaultHandler` class, and everything worked fine until today; I now have troubles because the feed file includes this line:

```
<description>°</description>
```

So I get an exception described like this:

```
org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 102, column 13: not well-formed (invalid token)
```

How could I fix this situation? What should I do to avoid this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770460/parse-error-exception) suggests you need to set the encoding correctly on your input source. The snippet from the article gives the following solution, using the appropriate encoding for your data (two examples given here):

```
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(is);
//inputSource.setEncoding("iso-8859-1");
inputSource.setEncoding("utf-8");
```

Comment: The first line of the xml should contain a header and optionally an encoding. This should match what you set above. If there isn't one then the parser will default to the system encoding. If you can open the xml feed in a browser you'll be able to see the encoding. The default encoding on windows is Windows-1521, which you could also try.